# Is the child element visible in the parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a comment system, there is a certain block in which there are others (messages) how, when scrolling through these messages, to find out whether the user sees one particular one (for example, with the identifier x) or not,

HTML:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="msg" id="a"></div>
  <div class="msg" id="b"></div>
  <div class="msg" id="c"></div>
  <div class="msg" id="x"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: 89%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.msg {
    width: 98%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px hsl(174deg 72% 41%) solid;
    color: hsl(174deg 72% 41%);
    border-radius: 20px
px
;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```js
document.querySelector(".parent").onscroll = () => {
  //what to write here?
}
```

That is: if the message has become visible in the general block, then paint it in yellow

I tried different options: getComputedStyle, and getBoundingClientRect, and offset, but none of this helped me, they constantly say that the message is visible

BUT:
getBoundingClientRect doesn't work, I don't need to check if it's visible in the whole window, I need to check if it's ONLY visible in a div element

WHEN SCROLLING A PARENT ELEMENT

Comment: You could try [ru.so], but you should check their help center first to make sure the question is on-topic.

Comment: Hey @Bot, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question must be in English, or you could use [srackoverflow.ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) instead. / Привет, Bot, добро пожаловать в StackOverflow! Ваш вопрос должен быть на английском языке, или вы можете использовать [srackoverflow.ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вместо этого.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564266/check-if-a-piece-of-the-element-is-in-viewport

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564266/check-if-a-piece-of-the-element-is-in-viewport doesn't work, I don't need to check if it's visible in the whole window, I need to check if it's ONLY visible in a div element

Comment: @bot as others have mentioned by linking to an already answer question here on SO, I believe that you could use the [`Intersection Observer API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by other user, what you are looking for is the Intersection Observer API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Here's a demo trying to apply the concept to your scenario. It's not very well factored but clearly shows a document containing both your `.msg` container (`.parent`) styled as `overflow-y: scroll;` and other elements before and after taking space on the viewport.

All `.msg` elements will be observed for intersection in the visible space of their parent so that every time each one of them will be visible, its id will be printed on console. Plus there's an added `trigger` callback that will be invoked in the event described above, that will check for a condition (for example if the element currently became visible has `id == 'c'`) to perform an action.

```js
//this will be called everytime a target element being observer became visible,
//and will check a condition before performing an action (if the element.id === c for example)
const trigger = (element)=>{
  if (element.id === 'c')
    console.log('condition met! element with id == c was reached.');
}

const observerOptions = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0
};

//gets called everytime any of the targets appears on the viewport
const observerCallback = (entries, observer) => {
  //for each of the observed entries
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    //console logs the element id currently intersecting the viewport 
    if (entry.isIntersecting){
      console.log(entry.target.id);
      trigger(entry.target);
    }
  });
};

//sets up an observer...
//calling the observerCallback when the observed targets will be intersecting the viewport
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);

//the targets the observer will be observing for (each .msg children inside the .parent element)
const observerTargets = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > .msg');
observerTargets.forEach(target => observer.observe(target));
```

```css
.other-content{
  display: block;
  outline: dashed 3px gray;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: gray;
}

.parent {  
  display: block;  
  margin: 10px 10px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;  
  outline: solid 1px gray;
}

.msg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;  
  height: 200px;      
  
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;  
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 2px hsl(174deg 72% 41%);
  border-radius: 10px;     
}

.msg::before {  
  position: absolute;
  content: 'id: ' attr(id);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;  
  background: gray;
  
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;  
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="other-content">
  before..
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="msg" id="a"></div>
  <div class="msg" id="b"></div>
  <div class="msg" id="c"></div>
  <div class="msg" id="x"></div>
</div>

<div class="other-content">
  ..after
</div>
```