# Is there a way to prevent user from scrolling until certain area has been reached?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make code so that until the user reaches a certain point on my page, they won't be able to scroll down to see the rest of the page. Is there a way to do this?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tabs">
    <input id="age" type="radio" name="slider" checked>
    <input id="ethnicity" type="radio" name="slider">
    <input id="both" type="radio" name="slider">
    <div class="buttons">
        <label for="age">1/3</label>
        <label for="ethnicity">2/3</label>
        <label for="both">3/3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box age">
            <div class="chart-parent">
                <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h1>Age</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Exercitationem placeat unde illum doloremque cumque beatae 
                veritatis nulla, culpa autem sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box ethnicity">
            <div class="chart-parent">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h1>Race/Ethnicity</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Exercitationem placeat unde illum doloremque cumque beatae 
                veritatis nulla, culpa autem sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box both">
            <div class="chart-parent">
                <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h1>Race/Ethnicity vs. Age</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Exercitationem placeat unde illum doloremque cumque beatae 
                veritatis nulla, culpa autem sed.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="to-next">
    <div class="next-content">
        <h1>Next</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam ad iure quisquam culpa corporis eius praesentium 
        eos neque voluptatibus nesciunt, dolor doloribus, sapiente iusto dicta consequatur sunt illum, nulla facilis explicabo. 
        Incidunt ut dicta esse voluptas cupiditate, ducimus id molestiae reprehenderit? Ad, ipsum et. Laudantium possimus veritatis
        necessitatibus saepe molestias.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All of the 'box' classes are part of a slideshow, so they need to click one of the 'label' elements to read whats in each box. (example: click on the age label, it goes to box age). I want to make it so that the user cannot scroll down, until they have clicked on the last label, (<label for-"both">3/3). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should require them to check a box before you let them scroll down to the rest.

Comment: How could a user scroll below `box both` without passing `box both`?

Comment: Besides "Head Wizard Locke's" answer, another approach could be to hide (display:none) the lower-down content and show it again when the bottom of the initial content is visible within the viewport. In modern code you can use the intersection observer api - see [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64575731/17300)

Comment: Just don't display anything you don't want them to see until they've clicked that final image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to stop a user from scrolling past a point on the page.  In your case, you want to then modify the logic inside "doSomething" to flip a switch to allow them to then continue.  In this example I use "setTimeout" to force the user to pause for 1 second after scrolling 200 pixels.

It is scoped to the window, but you could scope it to a div or whichever element you prefer.  It can also be triggered on the X value, rather than the Y value scroll amount, with minimal changes.  You could also have something else modify the scrollRoadBump value ... like a click event on the labels you are talking about ... instead of using setTimeout, the clicking of the label would "open the gate" to the next "scroll road bump" simply by increasing the value, and that value could come from the window position of the next content element...

One challenge will be to calculate a scroll percentage that is device agnostic, which you can do this way:

```
window_percentage_scrolled=window.scrollY/window.height*100.0
```

```js
let lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;
let ticking = false;
let scrollRoadBump = 200;
let allowContinue = false;

function doSomething(scrollPos) {
  // Do something with the scroll position
  if ( !allowContinue && scrollPos > scrollRoadBump ) {
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollRoadBump );
    setTimeout(function(){allowContinue=true;},1000);  // pause for 1 second
  }
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      doSomething(lastKnownScrollPosition);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="content">
<p>Black spot no prey, no pay maroon Jolly Roger heave down bring a spring upon her cable ahoy red ensign execution dock prow. Cog broadside Shiver me timbers come about black jack gibbet parrel crack Jennys tea cup spyglass keel. Yard execution dock measured fer yer chains reef Jolly Roger hardtack keel swab rope's end coffer. Yawl square-rigged rigging Pirate Round mutiny wherry bucko aft pressgang Blimey. Code of conduct rutters crow's nest Jack Tar parley Davy Jones' Locker bilged on her anchor strike colors topsail scuttle.</p>
<p>Nelsons folly red ensign cable pressgang boom yawl yardarm Chain Shot transom spanker. Holystone cutlass Yellow Jack killick landlubber or just lubber long boat wench main sheet ho black jack. Knave bilge rigging schooner pinnace long boat Pirate Round ballast Plate Fleet Gold Road. Bilged on her anchor furl bilge rat yawl list trysail jury mast me Spanish Main code of conduct. Belay bilge water fore tackle bowsprit yawl bilge rat snow spanker reef.</p>
<p>Coxswain crow's nest overhaul code of conduct pressgang transom ho spirits holystone grog. Barbary Coast yard topgallant tender lass killick topmast Chain Shot rigging measured fer yer chains. Transom trysail execution dock topsail log red ensign gally jury mast pink chantey. Walk the plank broadside jolly boat transom bilged on her anchor cable nipper spanker pressgang ho. Overhaul spyglass trysail topsail dance the hempen jig yardarm keelhaul Buccaneer hardtack gaff.</p>
<p>Black spot no prey, no pay maroon Jolly Roger heave down bring a spring upon her cable ahoy red ensign execution dock prow. Cog broadside Shiver me timbers come about black jack gibbet parrel crack Jennys tea cup spyglass keel. Yard execution dock measured fer yer chains reef Jolly Roger hardtack keel swab rope's end coffer. Yawl square-rigged rigging Pirate Round mutiny wherry bucko aft pressgang Blimey. Code of conduct rutters crow's nest Jack Tar parley Davy Jones' Locker bilged on her anchor strike colors topsail scuttle.</p>
<p>Nelsons folly red ensign cable pressgang boom yawl yardarm Chain Shot transom spanker. Holystone cutlass Yellow Jack killick landlubber or just lubber long boat wench main sheet ho black jack. Knave bilge rigging schooner pinnace long boat Pirate Round ballast Plate Fleet Gold Road. Bilged on her anchor furl bilge rat yawl list trysail jury mast me Spanish Main code of conduct. Belay bilge water fore tackle bowsprit yawl bilge rat snow spanker reef.</p>
<p>Coxswain crow's nest overhaul code of conduct pressgang transom ho spirits holystone grog. Barbary Coast yard topgallant tender lass killick topmast Chain Shot rigging measured fer yer chains. Transom trysail execution dock topsail log red ensign gally jury mast pink chantey. Walk the plank broadside jolly boat transom bilged on her anchor cable nipper spanker pressgang ho. Overhaul spyglass trysail topsail dance the hempen jig yardarm keelhaul Buccaneer hardtack gaff.</p>
<p>Black spot no prey, no pay maroon Jolly Roger heave down bring a spring upon her cable ahoy red ensign execution dock prow. Cog broadside Shiver me timbers come about black jack gibbet parrel crack Jennys tea cup spyglass keel. Yard execution dock measured fer yer chains reef Jolly Roger hardtack keel swab rope's end coffer. Yawl square-rigged rigging Pirate Round mutiny wherry bucko aft pressgang Blimey. Code of conduct rutters crow's nest Jack Tar parley Davy Jones' Locker bilged on her anchor strike colors topsail scuttle.</p>
<p>Nelsons folly red ensign cable pressgang boom yawl yardarm Chain Shot transom spanker. Holystone cutlass Yellow Jack killick landlubber or just lubber long boat wench main sheet ho black jack. Knave bilge rigging schooner pinnace long boat Pirate Round ballast Plate Fleet Gold Road. Bilged on her anchor furl bilge rat yawl list trysail jury mast me Spanish Main code of conduct. Belay bilge water fore tackle bowsprit yawl bilge rat snow spanker reef.</p>
<p>Coxswain crow's nest overhaul code of conduct pressgang transom ho spirits holystone grog. Barbary Coast yard topgallant tender lass killick topmast Chain Shot rigging measured fer yer chains. Transom trysail execution dock topsail log red ensign gally jury mast pink chantey. Walk the plank broadside jolly boat transom bilged on her anchor cable nipper spanker pressgang ho. Overhaul spyglass trysail topsail dance the hempen jig yardarm keelhaul Buccaneer hardtack gaff.</p>
<p>Black spot no prey, no pay maroon Jolly Roger heave down bring a spring upon her cable ahoy red ensign execution dock prow. Cog broadside Shiver me timbers come about black jack gibbet parrel crack Jennys tea cup spyglass keel. Yard execution dock measured fer yer chains reef Jolly Roger hardtack keel swab rope's end coffer. Yawl square-rigged rigging Pirate Round mutiny wherry bucko aft pressgang Blimey. Code of conduct rutters crow's nest Jack Tar parley Davy Jones' Locker bilged on her anchor strike colors topsail scuttle.</p>
<p>Nelsons folly red ensign cable pressgang boom yawl yardarm Chain Shot transom spanker. Holystone cutlass Yellow Jack killick landlubber or just lubber long boat wench main sheet ho black jack. Knave bilge rigging schooner pinnace long boat Pirate Round ballast Plate Fleet Gold Road. Bilged on her anchor furl bilge rat yawl list trysail jury mast me Spanish Main code of conduct. Belay bilge water fore tackle bowsprit yawl bilge rat snow spanker reef.</p>
<p>Coxswain crow's nest overhaul code of conduct pressgang transom ho spirits holystone grog. Barbary Coast yard topgallant tender lass killick topmast Chain Shot rigging measured fer yer chains. Transom trysail execution dock topsail log red ensign gally jury mast pink chantey. Walk the plank broadside jolly boat transom bilged on her anchor cable nipper spanker pressgang ho. Overhaul spyglass trysail topsail dance the hempen jig yardarm keelhaul Buccaneer hardtack gaff.</p>
<p>Black spot no prey, no pay maroon Jolly Roger heave down bring a spring upon her cable ahoy red ensign execution dock prow. Cog broadside Shiver me timbers come about black jack gibbet parrel crack Jennys tea cup spyglass keel. Yard execution dock measured fer yer chains reef Jolly Roger hardtack keel swab rope's end coffer. Yawl square-rigged rigging Pirate Round mutiny wherry bucko aft pressgang Blimey. Code of conduct rutters crow's nest Jack Tar parley Davy Jones' Locker bilged on her anchor strike colors topsail scuttle.</p>
<p>Nelsons folly red ensign cable pressgang boom yawl yardarm Chain Shot transom spanker. Holystone cutlass Yellow Jack killick landlubber or just lubber long boat wench main sheet ho black jack. Knave bilge rigging schooner pinnace long boat Pirate Round ballast Plate Fleet Gold Road. Bilged on her anchor furl bilge rat yawl list trysail jury mast me Spanish Main code of conduct. Belay bilge water fore tackle bowsprit yawl bilge rat snow spanker reef.</p>
<p>Coxswain crow's nest overhaul code of conduct pressgang transom ho spirits holystone grog. Barbary Coast yard topgallant tender lass killick topmast Chain Shot rigging measured fer yer chains. Transom trysail execution dock topsail log red ensign gally jury mast pink chantey. Walk the plank broadside jolly boat transom bilged on her anchor cable nipper spanker pressgang ho. Overhaul spyglass trysail topsail dance the hempen jig yardarm keelhaul Buccaneer hardtack gaff.</p>
<p>Black spot no prey, no pay maroon Jolly Roger heave down bring a spring upon her cable ahoy red ensign execution dock prow. Cog broadside Shiver me timbers come about black jack gibbet parrel crack Jennys tea cup spyglass keel. Yard execution dock measured fer yer chains reef Jolly Roger hardtack keel swab rope's end coffer. Yawl square-rigged rigging Pirate Round mutiny wherry bucko aft pressgang Blimey. Code of conduct rutters crow's nest Jack Tar parley Davy Jones' Locker bilged on her anchor strike colors topsail scuttle.</p>
<p>Nelsons folly red ensign cable pressgang boom yawl yardarm Chain Shot transom spanker. Holystone cutlass Yellow Jack killick landlubber or just lubber long boat wench main sheet ho black jack. Knave bilge rigging schooner pinnace long boat Pirate Round ballast Plate Fleet Gold Road. Bilged on her anchor furl bilge rat yawl list trysail jury mast me Spanish Main code of conduct. Belay bilge water fore tackle bowsprit yawl bilge rat snow spanker reef.</p>
<p>Coxswain crow's nest overhaul code of conduct pressgang transom ho spirits holystone grog. Barbary Coast yard topgallant tender lass killick topmast Chain Shot rigging measured fer yer chains. Transom trysail execution dock topsail log red ensign gally jury mast pink chantey. Walk the plank broadside jolly boat transom bilged on her anchor cable nipper spanker pressgang ho. Overhaul spyglass trysail topsail dance the hempen jig yardarm keelhaul Buccaneer hardtack gaff.</p>
<p>Black spot no prey, no pay maroon Jolly Roger heave down bring a spring upon her cable ahoy red ensign execution dock prow. Cog broadside Shiver me timbers come about black jack gibbet parrel crack Jennys tea cup spyglass keel. Yard execution dock measured fer yer chains reef Jolly Roger hardtack keel swab rope's end coffer. Yawl square-rigged rigging Pirate Round mutiny wherry bucko aft pressgang Blimey. Code of conduct rutters crow's nest Jack Tar parley Davy Jones' Locker bilged on her anchor strike colors topsail scuttle.</p>
<p>Nelsons folly red ensign cable pressgang boom yawl yardarm Chain Shot transom spanker. Holystone cutlass Yellow Jack killick landlubber or just lubber long boat wench main sheet ho black jack. Knave bilge rigging schooner pinnace long boat Pirate Round ballast Plate Fleet Gold Road. Bilged on her anchor furl bilge rat yawl list trysail jury mast me Spanish Main code of conduct. Belay bilge water fore tackle bowsprit yawl bilge rat snow spanker reef.</p>
<p>Coxswain crow's nest overhaul code of conduct pressgang transom ho spirits holystone grog. Barbary Coast yard topgallant tender lass killick topmast Chain Shot rigging measured fer yer chains. Transom trysail execution dock topsail log red ensign gally jury mast pink chantey. Walk the plank broadside jolly boat transom bilged on her anchor cable nipper spanker pressgang ho. Overhaul spyglass trysail topsail dance the hempen jig yardarm keelhaul Buccaneer hardtack gaff.</p>
</div>
```